# OllyDbg - change loaded file name - Fix error caused by renamed file

Tags: ollydbg

There is a tool called LuteBot which is used in the game Mordhau to be able to make the player play midi files with the in game lute.

In the tool you need to specify the location of the file **DefaultInput.ini** from the game.

However, the tool does not work anymore since the game was updated and renamed the file "DefaultInput.ini" to "Input.ini". The tool still listens for the file "DefaultInput.ini" and if you try to add the location of "Input.ini" then you see an error message saying

> Please select the file "DefaultInput.ini

[image]

Is there a way to change the .exe to make it look for **Input.ini** instead of **DefaultInput.ini**?

I only found the text "DefaultInput" two times, it looks like those are methods:

[image]

```
openDefaultInputiniToolStripMenuItem
setDefaultInputiniLocationToolStripMenuItem
```

I figured it out by doing this:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- find your exe file. select it `right click` and select `View executable file`.
- press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and searched for "DefaultInput"

Comment: First of all, try the easiest approach, run `strings` on the executable and `grep` for the string (```strings lutebot.exe | grep -i defaultinput.ini```). If you can't find it, then the text is probably obfuscated. Place a break point on `CreateFile` or other file opening functions and look for where the string is being passed from. You can also backtrack using the stack when the message box gets displayed to see from where it branched from, place a break point, restart the program and keep on doing that till you find from where it passes the string.

Answer (score 1):

Googling it, it's actually an opensource software. Here is the [link](https://github.com/MontyLeGueux/Lutebot-2). Path resolution is done at line 90 in `LuteBot/IO/Files/SaveManager.cs`. Change the name of the `ini` file there.

If you just want to patch the string in the binary, make sure you search for unicode strings since C# will use unicode strings by default.

Comment: Good to know, but im still interested if this would be possible by using a debugger, since not every software is open source. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout the comment I made in your question then.